# How to set description to a field using swagger OpenAPI annotations

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

To improve our api documentation I want to add a description to a field of a response body

as an example see the default petstore spec here:  https://editor.swagger.io/

In the POST /pet
in the pet response, status has the description "pet status in the store"

How can I do this from an annotation perspective in my code base?

(swagger v3)

Comment: You are looking for @ApiModel annotation.

Comment: @ringadingding that annotation doesn't exist in the v3 library

Comment: I should have paid more attention to your question Viktor. It is recommended that "@ApiModel" should be replaced by "@Schema". You can find reference at following link https://springdoc.org/#swagger-ui-properties

Comment: @ringadingding
just letting you I managed to solve it :). Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 9, accepted):

solution in kotlin:

```
data class Pet(
        @field:Schema(description = "Pet status in the store")
        val status: String
     )
```

Answer (score 11):

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;

public class Pet {
    @Schema(description = "Pet status in the store")
    private String status;
}
```

thanks @viktor-baert

Comment: You can also add an example if you like for better explaining what will be in it: `description="Pet Status", example="sold"`